# Split text node

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div[contenteditable=true]. Text can be bold/italic/underline.

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <b>Text</b>
</div>
```

I need to split text node to 2 blocks:.

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <b>Te</b><b>xt</b>
</div>
```

Just for Chrome and Safari.

Comment: why do you need to split the text in such a way? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Since your request doesn't change the rendering of the text, what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Alnitak because there's always more than one way to skin a cat. Depending on **why** he wants to split one `b` tag into two, there might be a more appropriate solution. Context is important; this site is about helping solve people's problems, not just throwing code snippets at anyone who asks for them.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery. We have segments, user type some text and can split it. If text was formatted and I try split segment text formatting is reset.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [`Text.splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Text.splitText).

```
var b = document.querySelectorAll("div[contenteditable='true'] > *")[0];
var p = b.parentNode; // the element's parent
var t = b.firstChild; // the textNode content

var newText = t.splitText(2);    // splits the node, leaving it in place
var copy = document.createElement(b.tagName);  // make another wrapper
copy.appendChild(b.lastChild);  // move second text into the copy
p.insertBefore(copy, b.nextSibling);  // put the copy into the DOM.
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JbEnL/

As you specified Chrome and Safari I've used `querySelectorAll` to find the initial inner DOM element.

Comment: this will only split the text node; it won't go so far as duplicating the html tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to take the first bold tag in the div, and split the text in it among two bold tags:

Initial HTML:

```
<div id="target" contenteditable=true>
  <b>Text</b>
</div>​
```

Code:

```
var bold = document.getElementById("target").getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
var txt = bold.innerHTML;
bold.innerHTML = txt.substr(0,2);
var newBold = document.createElement("b");
newBold.innerHTML = txt.substr(2);
bold.parentNode.insertBefore(newBold, bold.nextSibling);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KsPrg/

​